# Cpu hot to touch

Tags: graphics-card, cpu

so its about almost 2 month's now that i had some huge games fps drops,
i decided to google and descover why this is happening, and i read an article which explains
the "dust" is some of the issue i completly cleaned the dust and still cPU is hot To touch
i cant even play a game fps droping to 1 and my tempture is 87,my nvidia card is also hot but not ho to touch. i tryed to unplug the fan which is located up to the cpu Clean it and plug it back still my cpu is over heatting so hard what should i do?

[image]

Comment: The image links do not work, please correct this.

Comment: I assume when you say your temperature is 87, this is your cpu temp you are referring to.  Anything above 80, your motherboard if newer should actually shut down to avoid damage so this is very hot.  I might suggest trying to reseat the cpu fan / heatsink if you know the fan is spinning.  This involves taking it off, cleaning the old thermal paste off, and applying some new thermal paste back on to both the cpu and the heatsink.

Comment: im referring to cpu tempture only not motherbord , but my nvidia card is also hot.

Comment: I would do as I suggested then ^. That hot of temperatures makes me think its not cooling properly so if the fan is spinning, you may as well check that the thermal paste is doing its job.

Comment: Also depending on your video card, you can get software to monitor its temperature too. You should see what its temps are too.

Comment: let me ask this if i replace my cpu chip with an older verison, would this work? becouse im not an expert but i think this should help?,

Comment: Well I wouldn't go down that road. For one thing, CPU's change pin configurations. If it is the same pin layout then I guess you could try but I don't really think this would solve it. Even if you tried a new one, you would still have to reapply thermal paste anyways.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete description of what you did? Did you separate the CPU from the heat sink? How did you clean the dust and what part(s) did you clean?

Answer (score 0):

73c is quite hot for a CPU and continued exposure to temps like this will permanently damage it.

Make sure all the fans inside your computer work and work correctly. Use canned air to clean lint or dust from the various intake vents on your computer and the heatsinks, but be careful that you do not cause the fans to spin too fast with the canned air as this can damage them. Holding the fans still while blowing through them is the best method.

Also, make sure your computer is not near a heater vent and has access to clean cool air from the rest of the room. Do not place your computer inside a closed cabinet.

If you can verify that your system has plenty of access to cool fresh air, that the fans are working and the heatsinks are not blocked with dust or lint, and the CPU is still registering temps in the 70s Celsius, check your processes using Task Manager (or Process Explorer from Sysinternals) for any processes that are using high percentages of the CPU. Check your task bar for running programs and turn off and disable any that you do not need. Use msconfig to further clean your start up programs.

As a last resort, format your system and reinstall the operating system if these other solutions still do not fix the problem.

UPDATE based on OP info:

OP had physically removed heatsink from CPU while cleaning and had failed to remove and reapply thermal paste before reassembling the unit.

Proper procedure dictates that any time a heatsink is removed from a CPU, the old thermal paste must be removed, and new thermal paste must be reapplied, otherwise the thermal conductivity will be compromised and your CPU has a high likelihood of overheating.

Comment: this computer has a fresh new system i just did it yestorday, i think its more like my cpu getting less air, i will try your tip, and eric f, thanks guys

Comment: Then you're having hardware issues. Which CPU do you have and are you running the stock cooler on it or an aftermarket one? What RPM is your CPU fan running at?

Comment: If it is new then I would definitely check the thermal paste. A lot of times on a new computer if the thermal paste isn't applied correctly it won't "bond" and then your temps would result as you said. It could have been an honest simple mistake by whomever assembled your computer.

Comment: Did you build the computer yourself @bar?

Comment: no, i bought it about 2 years ago from a company named ivory,

Comment: no eric it is not new, how do i check my rpm cpu fan? and afther a check its a stock cooler

Comment: I suppose there's a possibility the thermal paste may have baked, but if the issue is just happening now after running OK for 2 years, and there aren't other reasons to suspect it, I would be reticent to suppose it was the thermal paste.

Comment: yea i did find out that the thermal past has been destroyed and it looks like sort off (a picture from google) but mine is just lil bit i cleaned ithttp://www.building-a-computer.com/img/Final/too-much-thermal-paste-big.jpg    its not looking like this at all but it has some old white stuff on the sides which looks bad

Comment: Just is a possibility. I have had units before where it has been the cause after years. Generally speaking if there is a problem with the CPU in temperatures, it is the external cooling system (most likely), the motherboard / bios, or the CPU is defective (not very likely)

Comment: Eric what should i do in that case?

Comment: well i will try right now fixing the issue and i be back with an answer thanks guys

Comment: I would at least rule it out. Go buy a tube of thermal paste from your local computer store for a couple bucks. Clean off the top of the CPU and the bottom of the heatsink with rubbing alcohol.  Once dry, apply the thermal paste to both sides (look online for how much is good since you can find a pictue I am sure) and then reseat the heatsink

Comment: "yea i did find out that the thermal past has been destroyed" HOW? By taking the cooler off? Then you **definitely** need new paste. You can't put the cooler back again afterwards, the paste doesn't work twice.

Comment: Yes, if you ever take the heatsink off your processor, you always remove and reapply the thermal paste, even if it looks OK.

Comment: i took it off only for cleaning, aftherwards i found out that it was totally dust full , and that the thermal is done for ages, i just redo it and have my tempeture to 61 thanks for the help